# Is it possible to forge email info in header?

Tags: email, email-spoofing

I recently received an email from a guy making me a job offer for a big government company and stating that he works there.

However instead of using the domain of the company, he is using GMail.
Additionally I checked the header and it says

```
mail-wi0-x22a.google.com (mail-wi0-x22a.google.com. [2a00:1450:400c:c05::22a])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id at5si30958044wjc.111.2015.09.21.06.30.27
```

Which seems to be from Ireland (and I am located in Canada).
So now I am thinking of asking him to contact me using the domain of the company messaging system.

Thus I have a question: Will he be able to obtain gov.on domain email or fake it, and fake ip to be from Toronto Canada?

And as a side note. Should ignore the guy completely and not give him any personal info?

Comment: We cannot comment on whether to trust a random person on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your MX receives the message, it should write a line in the message headers showing the timestamp for this delivery, and the hostname and IP of the SMTP server that delivered this message to your MX.  This line would be difficult for the sender to forge, because it is your MX that writes it.  However, there may be a number of previous lines in the headers, denoting previous deliveries to various other SMTP servers that the message may have passed through en route to your MX.  These lines can easily be forged by the sender.